# Windows 10 Universal App - WinJS SplitViewCommand

Tags: windows-10, win-universal-app, winjs

I'm trying to use WinJS SplitView in my Windows Universal App.
I created new project and added code from this example: http://try.buildwinjs.com/

So my HTML looks like that:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>App1</title>

    <!-- WinJS references -->
    <link href="WinJS/css/ui-dark.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="WinJS/js/base.js"></script>
    <script src="WinJS/js/ui.js"></script>

    <!-- App1 references -->
    <link href="/css/default.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="/js/default.js"></script>
</head>
<body class="win-type-body">
    <div id="app">
        <div class="splitView" data-win-control="WinJS.UI.SplitView">
            <!-- Pane area -->
            <div>
                <div class="header">
                    <button class="win-splitviewpanetoggle"
                            data-win-control="WinJS.UI.SplitViewPaneToggle"
                            data-win-options="{ splitView: select('.splitView') }"></button>
                    <div class="title"><h3 class="win-h3">SplitView Pane Area</h3></div>
                </div>

                <div class="nav-commands">
                    <div data-win-control="WinJS.UI.SplitViewCommand" data-win-options="{ label: 'Home', icon: 'home'}"></div>
                    <div data-win-control="WinJS.UI.SplitViewCommand" data-win-options="{ label: 'Favorite', icon: 'favorite'}"></div>
                    <div data-win-control="WinJS.UI.SplitViewCommand" data-win-options="{ label: 'Settings', icon: 'settings'}"></div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <!-- Content area -->
            <div class="contenttext"><h2 class="win-h2">SplitView Content Area</h2> </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

When running the app almost everything works good. The only problem is with menu items (`SplitViewCommand`). They are not displayed.

When checking HTML `WinJS.UI.SplitView` and `WinJS.UI.SplitViewPaneToggle` is processed correctly but `WinJS.UI.SplitViewCommand` is not processed. It looks like app doesn't know what `WinJS.UI.SplitViewCommand` is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your version of WinJS library in base.js file. WinJS.UI.SplitView is avaliable in WinJS 4.0 and above, but support for WinJS.UI.SplitViewCommand object starts from WinJS 4.2.